# Material design icon fonts not found

Tags: vue.js, fonts, vuetify.js, material-design-icons

I am trying to use material design icons but getting squares rendered instead. I just found out in the console that vue is not finding the fonts of the icons, what I think is the problem.

The errors:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/fonts/vendor/material-design-icons-icondist/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff2?fa3334fe030aed8470dd560acd2df136 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (NOT FOUND)
GET http://localhost:8080/fonts/vendor/@mdi/materialdesignicons-webfont.woff2?9d0c9ec40cc136f00be859c4e9bb9e6c net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (NOT FOUND)
GET http://localhost:8080/fonts/vendor/material-design-icons-icondist/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff?1811d381e9d3e83343943bb574f8f2e1 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (NOT FOUND)
GET http://localhost:8080/fonts/vendor/material-design-icons-icondist/MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf?45c4a4612e18a3255f512feacd025fa9 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (NOT FOUND)
GET http://localhost:8080/fonts/vendor/@mdi/materialdesignicons-webfont.woff?ca644a1ac382257f441ed2bc75180172 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (NOT FOUND)
GET http://localhost:8080/fonts/vendor/@mdi/materialdesignicons-webfont.ttf?aa2aa53968801d79964332fddd975474 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

I am also using a font and a css loader:

```
module:{
        rules:[
            {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2|otf|eot|ttf|svg)(\?.*$|$)/,
                loader: 'url-loader?importLoaders=1&limit=100000'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                  'vue-style-loader',
                  {
                    loader: 'css-loader',
                    options: {
                      // enable CSS Modules
                      modules: {
                        // customize generated class names
                        localIdentName: '[local]_[hash:base64:8]'
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              },
        ]
    }
```

Does somebody know what's happening?